# Get Right or Left turn according to bearing value

Tags: android, navigation, geolocation, geometry, compass-geolocation

I have a three lat-lon coordinates that make up two lines A to B to C. There is also a function to calculate the bearing in android of a line A-B or B-C in 0-360 manner.I a calculating the left or right turn by doing as bearing(A-B)-bearing(B-C) if the difference is +ve assuming as Right if -Ve i am taking as Left... It work for many cases but for some cases it does not work... The case which does not work is

A-Lat:17.445849, Lng:78.501665 B-Lat:17.445255, Lng:78.501619 C-Lat:17.444593, Lng:78.503553

Bearing of A-B is 184 Bearing of B-C is 109

Difference (A-B)-(B-C) is 75 which is +ve so it should be right but acutally in map it is left. so can any one give me good equation to get turning direction....

Answer (score 0):

oOOPS... I got the calculations wrong.

Here's a bit from a spread sheet, I just tested it..

```
=MOD(A1+540, 360) - MOD(B1+540, 360)
```

Negatives indicate left.  
Sorry about the other miss-guided code.

```
bool right = (( (a1 + 540) % 360 - (b1 + 540) % 360 ) > 0 );
```

Not quite accurate because zero change would be seen as left.. I'll leave that bit to you.

Comment: why to add 1000 is der any reason... its nt working after adding it also??